# Demonstration of some integrals

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I need help understanding the following integrals. Basically, I need help demonstrating them.

$$ \int \frac{du}{a²+u^2} = \frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1}\frac{u}{a} + C$$

$$ \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{a²-u^2}} = \sin^{-1}\frac{u}{a} + C$$

$$ \int \frac{du}{u(\sqrt{u²+a^2})} = \frac{1}{a} \sec^{-1}\mid\frac{u}{a}\mid + C$$

Comment: What do you mean by "demonstrating"? Does direction of the equality matter, i.e. would it suffice to differentiate the right sides? Or do you specifically want the method for evaluating the left sides?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know integration by substitution? If you do, can you see any trig formulas that will indicate good substitution approaches?

Comment: If you know how to go right to left, then the other direction follows. (Hint: implicit differentiation.)

Answer (score 3):

The way you find the derivatives of the inverse trig functions involves implicit differentiation and constructing right triangles. Assuming you know how to do this, you get

$$\frac{d}{du}\arctan(u)=\frac{1}{u^2+1}$$

Fundamental Thm of Calculus tells us this is equivalent to

$$\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}=\arctan(u)+C$$

To obtain the formula for arctangent you've shown simply requires some manipulation.

$$\int\frac{du}{u^2+a^2}=\int\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{du}{(u/a)^2+1}=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{a}\right)+C$$

Try using this approach on the other functions listed.

Comment: please avoid answering no effort questions